# how to show form data in struts 1

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config

I need to show data from a form object when a page loads. I call the action execute method which loads and set the data in form object. That action execute method sets "success" in

```
    mapping.findForward("success");
```

and then it goes to the following forward.

```
    <forward name="success" path="/pages/showDetails.jsp"/>
```

This opens up the showDetails jsp. But I am unable to find that how do I pass the form object to this jsp and show them on the jsp page. I have to use struts tag library and no JSTL.

Please help.

Comment: Gee I can't rightly remeber but in your config file you will have a reference to the action and the actionForm

Answer (score 0):

To get value of form object in Struts1 use this EL syntax:

```
'${formBeanBame.propertyName}'
```

Comment: Also i don't think it is right way. I should be able to pass form object to next view via struts-config.xml

Comment: can u give code hint on how to get value from request object?

Comment: Hey..sorry for wrong information , that scenario works in struts2. You just need to use updated result.I have checked it.Let me know if if doe's work for you.

Comment: I have to use struts tag and not JSTL of EL. :(
Please do the same using struts tags.

Comment: In case if it does't work or gives jasper exception.Probable cause can be that el requires jstl jar probably.I don't remember that exactly.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without El.Because other option will be using Scriptlet(Should be ignored).Struts2 has similiar kind of syntaxes know as OGNL,but strtuts1 does't have something like that.